# SpreadSheet - how to collect all the data from each sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I contact you because I am currently blocked with my formula...
here is the context :

i've a spreadsheet with 6 sheets, in sheet6 i need a formula to find each "ok" in the others sheets

i want to get colunm a b c d for sheets 1 2 3 when colunm h equal "ok"
i want to get colunm a b c e for sheet 4 when colunm i equal "ok"
i want to get colunm a b c d for sheet 5 when colum j equal "ok"

Example : if i've 2 lines with ok in sheet1, 1 line with ok in sheet2, 2 lines in ok in sheet 4 and 1 line with ok in sheet 5, result must to be in sheet 6 :

a b c d (sheet1)
a b c d (sheet1)
a b c d (sheet2)
a b c e (sheet4)
a b c e (sheet4)
a b c d (sheet5)

I tried to use :

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!A:J;'Sheet2'!A:J;'Sheet3'!A:J;'Sheet4'!A:J;'Sheet5'!A:J},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col10 = 'ok' OR Col9 = 'ok' OR Col8 = 'ok'",0)
```

it's work with sheet 1 2 3 because same structuration... but i don't know exactly how to manage the specific for sheet 4 and 5

thx in advance for ur help
i hope that is clear ^^

Comment: Don't tag Excel for Google sheets.

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVEMyvoCyVZVDbOnKm1FP6yUKGqTMmy-HjWaQzpWD1U/edit?usp=sharing - thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try stacking the for "result" columns from each sheets, and the for "search" columns from each sheet:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:D,Sheet1!H:H;Sheet2!A:D,Sheet2!H:H;Sheet3!A:D,Sheet3!H:H;Sheet4!A:C,Sheet4!E:E,Sheet4!I:I;Sheet5!A:D,Sheet5!J:J},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col5 = 'ok'",)
```

This way, you're creating a range with 5 columns, 4 for the result and 1 last one for looking the "OK"

---

UPDATE

I've updated it to your locale and actual names of sheets:

```
=QUERY({'Feuille 1'!A:D\'Feuille 1'!H:H;'Feuille 2'!A:D\'Feuille 2'!H:H;'Feuille 3'!A:D\'Feuille 3'!H:H;'Feuille 4'!A:C\'Feuille 4'!E:E\'Feuille 4'!I:I;'Feuille 5'!A:D\'Feuille 5'!J:J};"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col5 = 'OK'";)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx Martin, it's works ! :) i didn't know we can use \ to separate a range

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Given your settings, you can use curly brackets to create ranges, dividing with \ the columns and with ; the rows. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could make it work is using the following formula:

```
={QUERY({'Feuille 1'!A:J;'Feuille 2'!A:J;'Feuille 3'!A:J};
    "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col8 = 'OK'";0);
  QUERY('Feuille 4'!A1:I;"Select A, B, C, E where I = 'OK'";0);
  QUERY('Feuille 5'!A1:J;"Select A, B, C, D where J = 'OK'";0)}
```

Since the columns that you want from the `Sheet 4` are different, this break the query and doesn't import the rows correctly, this also breaks the `Sheet 5` which returns to the same patter of the first 3 sheets.

At the end, it will look like your expected result:

[image: test image]